# Flying-saucer ignores upper case css identifiers

Tags: css, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I recently start using flying-saucer library to generate a pdf from html web page. Everything works fine, except that the CSS rules, that look similar with the one below, are ignored.

```
TD.standardActiv
{
    FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
    COLOR: #1a467a;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #6f9bce;
}
```

If I change the 'TD' to 'td', everything is working properly. Does anyone know how to solve this? I thought about replacing all upper case identifiers, but it's an ugly solution, because of the amount of css files that should be updated.

Comment: Just use Find+Replace functionality to change `TD` to `td`. Unless you have five zillion CSS files spread out in ten zillion places, that's the best thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Download all the CSS's yourself and run them through some case converter code
2. The Powah of Open Source:  Change the underlying code to be case insensitive.
3. Update to a newer version of FS/iText.  This may have already been fixed.

Number 3 is trivial, but may not work.  Number 1 may not be practical, I'm not that familiar with Flying Saucer.

I'm a big fan of #2.  You'll probably have to modify the source to iText's `com.itextpdf/lowagie.text.html.simpleparsers.StyleSheet` class. The trunk already changes the tags to lower case, so I'm guessing #3 just might be all you need.

Comment: OTOH, Flying Saucer may have an entirely independent CSS system.  Dunno enough about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The #2 seems to be the a good idea to solve this problem. I will give it a try.

Comment: I actually had to modify the method 'matchesElement()' from DOMTreeResolver class, from FS jar. Rebuild FS, and now it's all working fine.